# Multiple different chart types stacked, column type with y value as color

Tags: highcharts

What is the best way to achieve a chart with multiple types when it should include a type that has the following kind of visual presentation.

```
| yellow   |blue|     gray      |  yellow |   gray   |
```

i.e. a type which is one dimensional (but visually has height), and the color indicates 'y' (which here consists of categories: yellow, blue, gray)

You should also be able to stack those:

```
| radical         | senseless |         high tension |
| yellow   |blue|     gray      |  yellow |   gray   |
```

I can achieve this with having a chart typed column with a series for each category:

http://jsfiddle.net/RCnYV/

But how can I also add another chart type above that, like:

```
yAxis (only for the line)
^                                                      ___
|-------            ___________________________   ____/
|       \__________/                           \/
|     radical         | senseless |         high tension |
|     yellow   |blue|     gray      |  yellow |   gray   |
-----------------------------------------------------------> xAxis (shared)
```

So the line series should be above (not hovering over) the others. Note that the xAxis is shared between all of the series, i.e. all of the series have exactly as many data points. It is just that some of the series are presented as type 'line', and others with the new type (that I don't know good name for, ribbon?).

Also what other ways are there to create a similar chart? One problem with the above is that I need to create one series for each catalog, that is 2 *  series in total, and not just two as would be the case with basic chart.

Comment: As far as 1 dimensional info is considered, pie seems to be good option

Comment: That is indeed one dimensional, but if I understand correctly, it cannot achieve the picture above. I need to have different category item presented multiple times, depending what x is. I should make a note that all series are related on xAxis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/cABfL/ ?
You can stack the charts by specifying `height`s for your yAxis, and manipulating its `top` so that they stack one over the other

```
        yAxis: [{
            top: 300,
            lineWidth: 2,
            offset: 0,
            height: 200,
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.series.name + ": " + $wnd.Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            }

            },
        {
            height: 200,
            lineWidth: 2,
            offset: 0,
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value + 50;
                }
            }

            }],
```

Similar stacking example is available @ http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume

**EDIT**
To answer to the second part of the question `(Also what other ways are there to create a similar chart?)`. There isn't anything out of the box that highchart seems to bring to the table for such a visualization, so you would need to work yourself around the existing lines and columns to get this visualization.

This is how I went about it.
I tried using the [stacked bar chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked) for each ribbon, hence would need 2 series, 1 for the line and 1 each for both the ribbons. But after giving it a try, turned out the bar chart is nothing but a rotated column chart (at least a sort of), it seems to have the vertical axis as the X and horizontal one as Y, hence it messes up any other chart, i.e. the line chart gets messed up as it wants the horizontal to be the X.

Basically using a bar chart didn't take me much far. I went ahead using the line chart (With a very thick line `lineWidth:50`) and drew a horizontal (Constant Y for each point) line chart with one series for each section of the ribbon, hence being able to give each section different color. Each ribbon would need a separate Y-axis, with different offset as mentioned above. Also removed all the tooltip, Y-axis labels and grid lines, to make it look as different from a line chart and more like the ribbon. Tooltip may be needed, but line charts give tooltip for points, in our case we want tooltip on section between two points, hence wrote a mouseOver event handler and calculated the length of the section in there. The only part that was hurting now was creating a series for each section of the ribbon, so went ahead and wrote the following utility function that accepted a list of values, basically the x intercepts for each section (you can improvise it to take section length instead) and returned an array of series.

```
    // usage: createSeries([0, 3, 4, 6], 1)
    // Creates 4 series and assigns them all to yAxis 1
    // you can extend this to take colors etc too, as per requirement
    function createSeries(data, yAxisIndex) {
        var i;
        var series = [];
        for (i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) { // Node lenghth-1
            var start = data[i];
            var end = data[i + 1];
            series.push({
                yAxis: yAxisIndex,
                animation: false,
                stack: 0,
                data: [[start, 0], [end, 0]],
                lineWidth: 50,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: function() {
                        return "";
                    }
                },
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {
                        alert(this.data[1].x - this.data[0].x);
                    }
                },
                showInLegend: false

            });
        }
        return series;
    }
```

All that was needed was to push these series into the existing series and then feed it to the highchart constructor.

**Final jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/cABfL/

Comment: That settles the first question, thank you! But I still need to find a better way to make 'ribbon' kind of chart where y-value is color. Namely, the way I put it in the example is way too slow for bigger graphs because my solution needs series for each value category. Do you have any idea for that?

Comment: You can use bar chart (1 chart for each row), but combining bar charts with line charts kind of ruins the x-axis. I am looking into getting that work

Comment: On a side note, shouldn't these be posted as two different questions?

Comment: Update, check this @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/cABfL/9/ Will edit the answer once I get some free time

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out in more detail later but does it support to have the same y-value / color to occur many times in one ribbon. e.g. | red | blue | red | yellow | red.

Comment: Every subsection of the ribbon is a series, and you can very much define colors for these series, and can repeat on need basis

Comment: Ok, it's a good solution, hopefully performance is good also!