# Highcharts - multiple plot with the same x scale

Tags: highcharts, axis, scatter-plot

I want to make a multiple plots with the x-axis aligned so that we can compare two set of data. I want it to look like this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11796553/229075

In my case there are some addition requirement that some of the plot are lines and some are bar. So the default scale does not align even if the data range are the same.

I found some good suggestion about "stacking" the charts. It is a little bit complicated but a promising way to try.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12179023/229075

However I also have other use case that may push the envelop of simple stacking. For example, I'd like to do scatter plot matrix sometime when both x-axis and y-axis have to align like this

http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/images/spmatrix3.png

Rather than putting many chart in one Highchart, this may requires have many separate charts but have better control in how the axis is layout.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use one one chart, you can use [linkedTo](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.linkedTo) option to connect axis.

If you want more simple charts, you can manage to connect axis using event [afterSetExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes), where you can call [setExtremes()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes%28%29) for another chart.

Comment: I used setExtremes to set the two charts to the same range but the grid still does not align. http://jsfiddle.net/tungwaiyip/WEcEt/21/

Comment: This is base on the stacking example in the second link. It aligns correctly. I need to work in the axis labels though.

http://jsfiddle.net/tungwaiyip/F3pts/6/

Comment: Sorry, missed your comment. With columns you have to set `pointRange` and for labels I advice to set fixed margins instead. See: http://jsfiddle.net/WEcEt/22/

Comment: Thank you. The example works. But once I tried to apply it to my apply it does not line up again. My x-axis is linear instead of datetime. And I'm not able to line them up http://jsfiddle.net/tungwaiyip/EdRuj/3/

Comment: I have this working with some trial and error. The key to line up bar chart with line chart is to set pointRange of the column chart to 0. And to compensate for the 0 width columns, set xAxis' min/maxPadding to 0.03. Sorry I have not get around to make a viewable demo.